# Ninject Service layer repo

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ninject

So, I know how to inject a service layer into a controller using the Kernel binding.

But if my service layer is needing an injection of a Repository of some kind in its constructor, how can I specify this?

The UI layer has project reference access to the Service project.

The service layer has access to the DAL project

I don't want to reference the DAL layer in the UI just to do the bindings.

what other way is there for the service layer to have a Repository interface to be injected in its constructor?

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Add a INinjectModule to your DAL library to do the bindings. similarly, provide one for your services layer. then, in the UI layer, when your app starts, do a `IKernel.Load()` and pass in a list of the assemblies for all your layers. it will automatically scan for Ninject Modules and perform the bindings.